# Which test to use for a constant model?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, modeling

Similar to how you would demonstrate a set of data is fit by a linear model, I would like to show that a list of data is fit by a constant model (i.e. $y \sim c$). But since the $R^2$ value compares against a constant baseline, I can't use this method.

I realize this problem is pretty badly defined, but if you could point me in a direction where I can provide some confidence that the data fits a constant model, that would be awesome.

Comment: The model is $Y=c+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a random error. What is the distribution of the error term? You can use the $R^2$ value, $R^2$ can be used for multiple regression models with 2, 3, 4, ... parameters, and also for a model with 1 parameter (the constant term)

Comment: @Hugh thank you for your response. The error term seems to be normally distributed.

Comment: @Hugh can you elaborate a bit more? How can we use an R^2 meaningfully if it compares against a constant baseline? In our tests, even though $y$ was quite constant, the R^2 value was around $0.1$.

Comment: The R-squared value (R2) can be calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" so that if you can calculate those two variance values, you can calculate the R-squared value manually. It can be interpreted as telling you how much of the data variance is explained by your model.

Comment: What exactly do you want to show? Why do you want to use something like $R^2$ in here? Notice that for any other regression model $R^2$ wouldn't either "prove" that data comes from such model. Since you are basically assuming that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(c, \sigma)$, you need only to test if normal distribution fits your data well.

Comment: @Tim thanks, I suppose you're right. Is there some "probability" that I can assign to this fit so that we can quantify how certain we are (probability?) that the data comes from a constant value plus a bit of noise?

Comment: How certain as compared to what? Assuming constant + noise means assuming that it is a random variable with some mean.